# Setting a larger font size for a TFS Query from within VS 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

There is a question in social.msdn.microsoft.com forums about setting the size of the font for the query results from a TFS query when run within VS 2013.  One answer is that these are Windows Display values (Only applied via reboot on my system); another answer is Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors.  However, that answer stops short of identifying the context.

Is there a way to temporarily set the font size (say, for displaying to a roomful of teammates on a large screen) when displaying the results from a TFS query?  (In the Text Editor, I can scroll the mouse while holding the Ctrl key, but in the TFS results query window, that scrolls horizontally for me.)

Comment: Have you tried using "zoom"?

Comment: Where is "zoom"?  I thought I'd looked every where!

Comment: My bad. It's there for text editors, not for the Work Item results.